# Invalid Write with strcpy

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have been programming for a while but I am new to C. I have this linked list implementation in ansi C that I need to test. I have narrowed the problem down to an issue with an invalid write. I ran the code through Valgrind and received the following output:

```
==18131== Invalid write of size 1
==18131==    at 0x4C2C0CC: __GI_strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64 linux.so)
==18131==    by 0x40089B: main (in /home/btm7984/hw3/TestList)
==18131==  Address 0x51f1388 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==18131==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18131==    by 0x400880: main (in /home/btm7984/hw3/TestList)
==18131==
==18131== Invalid write of size 1
==18131==    at 0x4C2C0DF: __GI_strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18131==    by 0x40089B: main (in /home/btm7984/hw3/TestList)
==18131==  Address 0x51f138e is 6 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==18131==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18131==    by 0x400880: main (in /home/btm7984/hw3/TestList)
==18131==
--18131-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting
--18131-- si_code=1;  Faulting address: 0x6D4FCAA;  sp: 0x402bdae00
```

All that I can ascertain from this is that I am allocating something wrong. I think it has to be with my strcpy line. I really don't know how to approach this question. What follows is my use of the LinkedLists interface. InitLinkedLists, AddToBackOfList, and DestroyList are all defined in that interface.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "LinkedLists.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  FILE *fp;
  char tmpString[100];
  LinkedLists *ListPtr = malloc(sizeof(LinkedLists));
  ElementStructs *DataPtr;
  LinkedListNodes* curr = malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNodes));
  int counter = 0;
  int Done = 0;

  InitLinkedList(ListPtr);
  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (!fp){
    fprintf(stderr,"%s Cannot open file %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
    exit(1);
  }
  do{
    fscanf(fp,"%s",tmpString);
    if (!feof(fp)) {
      DataPtr = malloc(sizeof(DataPtr));
      printf("%d   %d : %d\n",counter,(int)strlen(DataPtr->str),(int)strlen(tmpString));
      strcpy(DataPtr->str,tmpString);
      DataPtr->index=counter;
      AddToBackOfLinkedList(ListPtr, DataPtr);
      counter++;
      Done = 1;
    } else {
      Done = 0;
    }
  }while (Done);
```

In conclusion, I think strcpy is causing an invalid write and I don't know why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: ElementStructs is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct ElementStructs
   {
   /* Application Specific Definitions */
   int index;
   char str[100];
  } ElementStructs;
```

Comment: How is `ElementStructs` defined ?

Comment: `p = malloc(sizeof p)` is always wrong.

Comment: typedef struct ElementStructs
  {
   /* Application Specific Definitions */
   int index;
   char str[100];
  } ElementStructs;

Comment: followup on melpmene's comment, try `malloc(sizeof(*DataPtr))` ?

Comment: As a side note, Valgrind will be more helpful if you compile with debug information (`-g` for gcc). You should get line numbers in addition to function names.

Comment: malloc(sizeof(*DataPtr)) worked. Would malloc(sizeof(ElementStructs)) work better?

Comment: You should use sizeof with a datatxpe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem resides in this statement:

```
DataPtr = malloc(sizeof(DataPtr));
```

You allocate only enough memory to hold a pointer and not a full struct.

You should allocate using:

```
DatapPtr = malloc(sizeof(ElementStructs));
```

or, as described in the comments (WhozCraig):

```
DatapPtr = malloc(sizeof(*DataPtr));
```